# Call to derived class function in vector populated with variadic initializer list doesn’t behave polymorphically

Tags: c++11, polymorphism, variadic-templates

I am using an initializer list to declare an arbitrary number of item pairs at compile time, each consisting of a key and a real type as the value. There are two derived real types in the model code: MyA and MyB, both of which derive from My. The vector gets initialized with a key and a particular derived type like, {33, MyA}. I insert this set of initializations into a vector using std::initializer_list. The MyA and MyB constructors get properly called so I know the correct objects are getting constructed.

Being able to declare/instantiate  an arbitrary number of item pairs at compile time will greatly reduce the complexity of my prototype code by eliminating much redundant code and allowing me to easily add additional sets of pairs as the code matures.  itemVect1 in the model code works fine.

But when I make a call on MyAFunc(), itemVect1  executes the base class’s MyFunc().

Is there a way I can use this very powerful variadic code machinery and still maintain polymorphic access to various derived types which I want to pass in in the initializer list?

I built my model code off of the code in StackOverflow “Inserting a variadic argument list into a vector?”

```
struct My
{
  My() {}
  void MyFunc() {}
  virtual void MyAFunc() {}
  virtual void MyBFunc() {}
};

struct MyA : My
{
  MyA() : My() {}
  void MyAFunc() {}
};

struct MyB : My
{
  MyB() : My() {}
  void MyBFunc() {}
};

template< typename KeyT, typename ValueT >
struct ItemPair
{
  ItemPair( KeyT key, ValueT val )
    : key( key ), val( val ) {}
  KeyT key;
  ValueT val;
};

typedef ItemPair< const int, My > IPIntMy;

struct ItemPairVect
{
  ItemPairVect( std::initializer_list< IPIntMy > initList )
    : ipVect( initList ) {}

  std::vector< IPIntMy > ipVect;
};

int main()
{
  ItemPairVect itemVect1 { IPIntMy { 33, MyA {} }, IPIntMy { 44, MyB {} }, IPIntMy { 55, MyA {} }, IPIntMy { 66, MyB {} } }; // works fine
  itemVect1.ipVect[ 0 ].val.MyAFunc(); // doesn't behave polymorphically, that is, it calls MyFunc() instead
}
```

I tried changing My to My* in the typedef which is the normal way to make an object polymorphic, but had problems getting the initializer list to parse.

Comment: Slicing. You can't store derived objects by value as base objects. Use `std::unique_ptr`'s to add the required indirection.

Comment: But where would I create the std::unique_ptr? Easy to declare, but not sure how I would do a std::make_unique.

Comment: `typedef ItemPair< const int, std::unique_ptr<My>> IPIntMy;`, and then `make_unique` when you fill your container in `main()` :)

Comment: But I would like for the container to be filled without  having to "fill my container" as a separate step. I can see by stepping through the initialization code, that at some point a 'new' is called for pointers to my initialization list values. I can also see that a default 'alloc' method gets called with a 'do nothing' in it. Normally, I would think this means that I can replace the default alloc with the std::make_unique. No?

Comment: I just noticed the same question in another posting: "Calling virtual method of base template from derived variadic template class". His answer was to use 'using', but I'm not even sure that is C++ and downcasting. I think std::unique is more logical so I want to get that working.

Comment: It's not an issue with templates or anything. By storing `ValueT val;` (i.e `My val;` after specialization) by value, you can only store a `My`, not anything derived from it (where would additional fields go ?). This is called slicing, because only the base class part of the derived instance is copied across, while the rest is sliced off. To fix it, you must store a polymorphic handle (pointer or reference) to your base class. `std::unique_ptr` fits the bill because it's a pointer which ensures automatic lifetime by default. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] I'm not sure what you mean with "separate step", just replace `IPIntMy { 33, MyA {} }` with `IPIntMy { 33, std::make_unique<MyA>() }`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88275/discussion-between-rtischer8277-and-quentin).